# making Emergency lighting normal supply and power failure

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, relay, dc

How can i make an emergency light that works in normal power supply & also in power failure.
Light will be always in ON condition,In normal condition power from normal power supply,and from power failure power taken from the battery.
please give me necessary advise or circuit diagram...

Comment: Is this project just for your own education/amusement? If there is any chance that someone may need to rely on this light in an emergency, then you should find out which standards are applicable and may be legal requirements in your country, eg IEC 60598-2-22.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGIclg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here you go. You just need two diodes rated to carry the maximum lamp current. The higher of the two voltages will power the lamp. The diodes prevent current from one power source running backwards into the other. The mains power supply voltage needs to be slightly higher than the battery's.

Comment: @sooraj: I've removed your edit. It doesn't make sense for you to edit my answer to your question. You can however post your own answer to your own question (if you found a good answer yourself after further research, for example) so you can do that with the additional schematic.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit shown below will work automatically as long as the DC supply is plugged/hardwired into the mains.

With the mains active, the DC supply will energize K1 and the supply's output will be connected to the lamp through the made NO and COM contacts. In case of a mains or a power supply failure K1 will be de-energized and  the battery will be connected to the lamp through the NC and COM contacts.

[image]

Comment: to work automaticaly what can we do?

Comment: @sooraj, ask yourself what happens if the relay switches. How would the relay switch?

Comment: @sooraj: See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit with the two diodes makes sense if the battery is not rechargeable.  If it is rechargeable, then you want the power supply to not only run the light when external power is available, but to keep the battery charged.  In that case you rearrange things as such:

[image]

In this example I used a typical 12 V sealed lead-acid battery because those are readily available and can tolerate being held at the float voltage for long periods of time.  You'd get a power supply that can be adjusted a bit to keep the battery at its long term float charge voltage.  Car batteries are kept at around 13.6 V when the engine is on.  For long term use, you probably want to use a little lower voltage.  The 13.5 V in series with a Schottky diode I show isn't meant to be a spec, just a number I picked that's probably not too far off.  The battery datasheet should give you the long term float voltage.

If the power supply can't be back-fed, then D1 can be removed (replaced with a short).  Without a specific spec that the power supply can't be back-fed, assume it can be and put the diode there.

The LEDs are just meant to show the connections to the "light".  This could be implemented as a series string of LEDs with a suitable resistor.  Better would be a small switching power supply that keeps a constant current thru the LED string and can tolerate some variation in its input voltage.  This should be from the minimum battery voltage to the charging voltage.

If using a switching power supply, it should have smarts to shut off when the battery gets so low that it would be damaged by additional current draw.

The same thing can be done with other batteries.  For example, a single lithium rechargeable would be quite appropriate here.  In that case, D1 would be replaced with a smart charging circuit that carefully monitors the battery voltage and keeps it charged properly.  This would be some sort of buck switcher with smarts, so you can start with any convenient power supply voltage a little higher than the maximum battery voltage, like 5 V.

The light driver would be a boost switcher that regulates the current thru the LED string, but also watches the battery voltage and shuts off to prevent damage when it gets too low.

Even more advanced would be to not use a off the shelf DC power supply.  Since everything can be well sealed and insulated, the DC power supply does not need to be isolated from the wall power.  The battery charger could be a buck switcher that works directly from rectified line power, for example.

If you just want to solve the problem as apposed to learning about the circuit or the experience of designing and building it, then go get a off the shelf unit.  There are lots of emergency lights of various types out there that do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are off-the-shelf solutions, eg: [MeanWell AD-55A](http://www.meanwell.com/mw_search/AD-55/AD-55-spec.pdf) - power supply, charger and battery protection. You can connect 12V LED bulbs directly, the power supply will protect the battery against overdischarge.